# How to flexibly change PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, organization, pythonpath

To specify the classpath in Java, I use the `-cp` or `-classpath` option to `java`. What is the equivalent option in Python?

I know I can set the OS variable `PYTHONPATH` but there shouldn't be one `PYTHONPATH` to rule them all.

I sometimes use PyDev in Eclipse. It can handle multiple source directories. How?

I often have multiple source directories. Sometimes I separate production and testing code. Sometimes I have a Git submodule with with some Python packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> To specify the classpath in Java, I use the -cp or -classpath option
>   to java. What is the equivalent option in Python?

Well, there's no "equivalent option" in Python as far as I'm aware, but any Unix-like shell will let you set/override it on a per-process basis, if you were to run Python like this...

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/put/path/here python myscript.py
```

...a syntax which you could also use for Java with...

```
$ CLASSPATH=/put/path/here java MyMainClass
```

The closest Windows equivalent to this would be...

```
> cmd /c "set PYTHONPATH=\put\path\here && python myscript.py"
```

...if you don't want the environment variable to be set in the calling `cmd.exe`.

> I sometimes use PyDev in Eclipse. It can handle multiple source
>   directories. How?

When running code, it probably does something similar by setting the variable in the [`execve(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) call.

Comment: The per-process single command was what I was looking for. Does anyone know a way to do this with Windows too?

Comment: @PaulDraper If you mean in `cmd.exe`, I think you have to do it in two calls, i.e. `SET PYTHONPATH=blah` then `python blah`. You could wrap it in a batch file, but it would remain set after the batch file terminated, unless you wrapped the batch file with another batch file which used `CALL` to call it, which, IIRC, creates a new environment.

Comment: @PaulDraper actually, there's an easier way - see updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

To do this programmatically, you use the following code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('directory')
```

If necessary you could specify the directory to append from a command line argument.

Depending on what exactly your aims are, this might not be the best solution, but for small one-off kinds of issues, it works alright.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) is for.

Comment: Yes...I looked at that, but I though I must have mistaken about its use. since nobody would require that, just where a simple command line arg could have sufficed...